# Regex match only with 'n' subfolders

Tags: regex

I have two types of urls

URL class 1 is of form:

> /category/state/city

URL class 2 is of form:

> /category/state/city/thing

I want to match class 1 but not class 2 of URLs.
I keep trying to exclude URLs with more than 3 forward slashes, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

Should do the trick.

It finds three groups of characters that are not slashes, but are separated by slashes.

The ^ at the start makes it start matching from the start of the input, and the $ at the end makes it only match if the whole input matches.

If you just want categorya, then try this:

```
^/categorya/[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

Comment: Thanks! So extra credit: If wanted the category to be a specific category (say category A) - so capture /categoryA/state/city but not /categoryB/state/city or any /category/state/city/thing

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Been spending a couple of hours in Regex101 not getting anywhere. Really appreciate.